# SSRS Upload reports with SOAP in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, soap, reporting-services

I am using this [SSRS-API](https://github.com/realityforge/ssrs-api) in my JAVA project, with SQL Server Reporting Services. With this API I can access my SSRS folders and Reports but I want to know if its possible to upload or Export reports in Excel or PDF.

Here is the SSRS java class : [SSRS.java](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/realityforge/ssrs-api/master/src/main/java/org/realityforge/sqlserver/ssrs/SSRS.java)

And my Managed bean :

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "biController")
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class BiController {

    private final String ADDRESS = "http://SERVERNAME/reportserver/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl";
    private String[] listReports;
    private SSRS ssrs;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(null, ADDRESS, new sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler());
            NTLMAuthenticator.setDefault(new NTLMAuthenticator("DOMAIN", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD"));
            ssrs = new SSRS(url, "");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new FacesException();
        }
    }

    // This function let me have the Report's names
    public void constructListOfReports(String path) {
        listReports = ssrs.listReports(path);
    }

    public String[] getListReports() {
        return listReports;
    }

    public void setListReports(String[] listReports) {
        this.listReports = listReports;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I used the download function (**downloadReport**) of SSRS api I mentioned above ([SSRS-API](https://github.com/realityforge/ssrs-api)), here is the code of the function :

```
public void downloadReport(final String path, final String filename) {
    final File file = new File(filename);
    final String physicalName = toPhysicalFileName(path);

    info("Downloading Report with symbolic name " + path + " to " + file);

    final byte[] data = _soap.getReportDefinition(physicalName);

    try (final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        out.write(data);
    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
        final String message = "Failed to download report with symbolic name " + path + " to " + file;
        LOG.warning(message);
        if (file.exists() && !file.delete()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(message + " and failed to delete temporary file", ioe);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(message, ioe);

        }
    }
}
```

And here is the function that I use to call this function :

```
public void downloadReport() {
    ssrs.downloadReport('Path/Report name', 'C:\\PATH\\TO\\A\\FOLDER\\REPORT.XML');
}
```

And in the given path (C:/PATH/TO/A/FOLDER/REPORT.XML) I get an XML file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="PercallAnalysisDW">
      <DataSourceReference>Entrepôt de données Percall Analysis</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>3a3e3aa4-c6d6-4b44-80f0-f18a9ecd2eac</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DeliveryMarginCumuleDS">
      <SharedDataSet>
        <SharedDataSetReference>DeliveryMarginCumuleDS</SharedDataSetReference>
      </SharedDataSet>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="Date">
          <DataField>Date</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Projet">
          <DataField>Projet</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="LABOR_facturé">
          <DataField>LABOR_facturé</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="TL_facturé">
          <DataField>TL_facturé</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Coût_total">
          <DataField>Coût_total</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="DM">
          <DataField>DM</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Revenu">
          <Value>=Fields!LABOR_facturé.Value + Fields!TL_facturé.Value</Value>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <ReportItems>
          <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
            <TablixBody>
                ...
```

Comment: Yes I would say that would be possible.

Comment: @BobBrinks can you please tell me how ? thanks

Comment: Well either there's a call in SSRS (never used it wouldn't know) that produces a PDF or an Excel. Or you would have to build some java code or find a library that takes data from SSRS and formats that data as PDF or Excel.

Comment: This is the point where I am stuck, I am always searching for a library that do this, or just something to show me the logic to get this data from the SSRS, if you know tutorials or something to help it will be great, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by generating reports with URL, here is the function that allows me to generate reports :

```
public void downloadReportExcel(String path) {
    try {
        String url = "http://" + SSRS_IP + "/ReportServer?/" + path + "&rs:Format=Excel";

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);

        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new FacesException(e);
    }
}
```

The function get a path in parameters and redirect me to the server url with 2 parameters:

- ?/path : is the full path (from the root folder) of the report to generate
- rs:Format=Excel : is the format of the generation (here I want to export the report to Excel, but It can take PDF, like : &rs:Format=PDF)